# Command-line access to MySQL with MAMP is not working

Tags: mysql, shell, command-line, terminal, mamp

I get the following error when I open MAMP: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTDGH.png

I changed the password via the Terminal, and all seemed well. I then changed it in the three other relevant files. I then added MAMP to the PATH so the MySQL command would be recognized. It wasn't recognized still, so I rebooted, and now it 'works', yay.

But when I type `mysql -p` and type in my password, it says Access denied.

Why? And what does the error mean?

I should add that the start page loads fine.

Comment: Look at the exact error you get. For me, `mysql -p` doesn't attempt to log me in as root; it tries to log me in with my OS username (which may not even exist as a mysql account). To test logging in as root, use `mysql -u root -p` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, turns out you need to edit this file as well and change -p`root` to -p`newpassword`.